# Are context.startService() calls guaranteed to be aquired by the service in the same order they were sent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Are context.startService() calls guaranteed to be aquired by the service in the same order they were sent?

consider in activity:

```
Intent intent;

intent = new Intent(MyIntents.ADD_BATCH_ACTION);
intent.putExtra(MyIntents.BATCH_ACTION_NAME, "Bake donuts");
startService(intent);

intent = new Intent(MyIntents.ADD_BATCH_ACTION);
intent.putExtra(MyIntents.BATCH_ACTION_NAME, "Make a coffee");
startService(intent);

intent = new Intent(MyIntents.ADD_BATCH_ACTION);
intent.putExtra(MyIntents.BATCH_ACTION_NAME, "Fetch coffee and donut to room 12");
startService(intent);

startService(new Intent(MyIntents.FLUSH_ADDED_ACTIONS));
```

Some action can hve much common work, I could optimize service if i were sure that they are executed in a batch.

Can I assume that service onStartCommand would be executed in the same order ?

regards, Tomek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are context.startService() calls guaranteed to be aquired by the service in the same order they were sent?

While I think they happen to occur in order, AFAIK this is not documented behavior, and therefore I would not count upon it.

> Some action can hve much common work, I could optimize service if i were sure that they are executed in a batch.

Then only call `startService()` once, with everything in your "batch". Intent extras support arrays for many types, so try packaging an array of extras instead of just one.

Comment: I agree with this assessment. Anecdotally, if you are making these calls on the main thread and your service is in the same process, I have always seen startService() intents handled in the order provided. The reason for this is that onStart() and onStartCommand() both execute on the main thread and must "complete" before your startService() call can even return.

Comment: You're generally right, but i hoped to be able to batch actions from different activities and then flush from another activity. For example a 3 step form interface, or a queue of tasks to be executed together for optimization -> they all share common resources but are logically independent.